# SQLAlchemy object passed to class looses changes

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I seem to have a problem with passing SQLAlchemy objects to other classes.

The problem is as follows: I have certain Flask module that's inside app.py. From there, I initialize an object from another class, let's call that class A and the object a. I also initialize a SQLAlchemy object called file (from model File), and I pass it ro the class as follows:

app.py:

```
file = File(...)
db_session.add(file) # db_session is a scoped session
db_session.commit()
a = A(file=file)
a.do_stuff()
file = db_session.merge(a.file)
```

A.py

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, file)
        self.file = file
    def do_stuff(self):
        self.file.some_attr = 'new_value'
        db_session.commit()
```

The changes done in A or lost, never commited. Am I using a wrong design pattern here or is there something else going one?

Comment: In `A.py` do you import `db_session` or create a new one ? Also in `A.py` you should add `db_session.add(self.file)` before `db_session.commit()`

Comment: I do import db_session, but I do not call it (e.g. `sess = db_session()`). It's scoped and I checked that all sessions in all modules are exactly the same.

Interesting, I should use `db_session.add(...)` even if the object already exists (even in the database)?